# GL ERROR: 1282 - Invalid operation

Tags: java, opengl, lwjgl

My code  is this:

```
   glColor4f(1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f);
    glEnable(GL_TEXTURE_2D);

    glBegin(GL_TRIANGLES);

    int bunnyDisplayList = glGenLists(1);
    glNewList(bunnyDisplayList, GL_COMPILE);

    List<Model> models = NPC.getModels();

    glBegin(GL_TRIANGLES);

    for (Model m : models) {
        for (Model.Face face : m.getFaces()) {
            Vector3f n1 = addVectors(m.getNormals().get(face.getNormalIndices()[0] - 1), m.getPosition());
            glNormal3f(n1.x, n1.y, n1.z);
            Vector3f v1 = addVectors(m.getVertices().get(face.getVertexIndices()[0] - 1), m.getPosition());
            glVertex3f(v1.x, v1.y, v1.z);
            Vector3f n2 = addVectors(m.getNormals().get(face.getNormalIndices()[1] - 1), m.getPosition());
            glNormal3f(n2.x, n2.y, n2.z);
            Vector3f v2 = addVectors(m.getVertices().get(face.getVertexIndices()[1] - 1), m.getPosition());
            glVertex3f(v2.x, v2.y, v2.z);
            Vector3f n3 = addVectors(m.getNormals().get(face.getNormalIndices()[2] - 1), m.getPosition());
            glNormal3f(n3.x, n3.y, n3.z);
            Vector3f v3 = addVectors(m.getVertices().get(face.getVertexIndices()[2] - 1), m.getPosition());
            glVertex3f(v3.x, v3.y, v3.z);
        }
    }
    glEnd();
    glEndList();
```

The models get drawn(but in a transparent way), but every time I call this function I get the following error:

```
GL ERROR: 1282 - Invalid operation
```

Comment: Which function? glNormal3f? What's the stack trace?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are calling `glBegin(GL_TRIANGLES);` twice. Remove the second statement.

Comment: no, you cannot remove the second - you need to remove the first one, otherwise, the display list is invalid.

Answer (score 0):

You have two calls to [glBegin](https://www.opengl.org/sdk/docs/man2/xhtml/glBegin.xml) before a call to glEnd. From the documentation, this will generate a GL_INVALID_OPERATION (1282). I would guess you should just remove the first one, if you're intending to draw the model in a display list.

Comment: "*I would guess you should just remove the first one*" You have to remove the first one. You can't do `glNewList` in a glBegin/End bracket.